# Unexpected result from xlrd sheet.nrows

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

[image]

I have an Excel sheet as such and a call to numrows as such:

```
sheet = self.rbook.sheet_by_index(0)
numrows = (sheet.nrows)
```

returns a value of `6` instead of `5`. There is nothing in any of the cells to the right of column 0, 1, or 2 in the sixth row.

I made some mock Excel files, one with nothing in it and it correctly returned `0`.

Comment: Are you still using Excel 2003?  In Excel put your cursor in cell A1, then press Ctrl+Shift+Del. What range is highlighted? Sometimes, Excel's interpretation of the sheet's `UsedRange` differs from what you might except, and this can be caused by a variety of factors.

Comment: It's possible that somewhere in row 6, there is an *apparently, but not actually empty* cell. For instance a cell containing a `' '` would cause this.

Comment: @DavidZemens I am not using Excel 2003, but I am using Xlrd which only supports .xls files (excel 2003).

Comment: @DavidZemens  Upon checking, it seems that in row 6 there is indeed ' ', which is not an empty cell apparently. That said I'm not very fond of excel for these reasons. The problem I have, is my code is supposed to determine which cell to start from based on a blank. So if there are no blanks in the first column, then it moves on to the second column and when it finds a blank it starts from there...but if it is interpreting the file as having 6 rows, with the 6th row as having blanks, things don't work.

Comment: Hmmmm I have xlrd right now working with xlsx file extension... AFAIK you can use it with 2007 and 2010 but I have not tested on 2013 yet.

Comment: In any case, this isn't an issue with Excel, nor with XLRD. They're both doing exactly what they ought to do in this case, and you'll need some sort of custom solution. Give me a few minutes and I'll try to put something together for you...

Comment: My interpretation was "out of sight, out of mind", i.e. that if there are no values in any of the cells, that row doesn't exist. I'll appreciate any kind of suggestion.

Comment: In which platform are your working? The number of `nrows` in macOS is one bigger than that in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  As hinted at in the comments, a string consisting of a single space (`" "`) *is* a value, so that is why the XLRD is returning 6, as you have some of these values in row 6.

Basically the approach here is to use a custom function arrive at the "last row" in your worksheet. This function iterates the `col_values` for the specified `col_num`.  So in your function you can do like:

```
numrows = getLastRow(sheet, 0)
```

By making `col_num` a parameter you can pass to this function, it allows some flexibility to query different columns without requiring a different function or totally different branch of logic to accommodate, and you can omit the optional `col_num` argument to return the native `nrows` property.

```
def getLastRow(sh, col_num = None):
  """
  ;param sh: Excel worksheet
  ;param col_num: long/integer identifying which column to query
  """
  if not col_num == None:
    return sh.nrows

  for r in range(sh.nrows,1,-1):
    if str(sh.col_values(col_num)[r-1]).strip() == '':
      print 'cell({},{}) contains an empty value or trims to empty string'.format(r, col_num)
    else:
      return r
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, I use this simple construction:

```
number_of_rows = 0
try:
    while current_sheet.cell(number_of_rows,0).value != '':
        number_of_rows += 1
except:
    number_of_rows -= 1
```

You can count number of rows, and number of cols. Just replace 'number_of_rows, 0' for '0, number_of_rows'

Simple, bad, but works :-)